# Clojure : is there a more idiomatic way to work on nested vectors?

Tags: clojure

I want to cap samples that I generate from Poisson's distributions.
Original data is like

```
[[2 12] [3 14]] (samples)
```

Here, [2 12] correspond to samples of distributions [P1 P2], [3 14] as well.
I want to cap P1 and P2 with max values, let's say for instance

```
[4 12] (max-values)
```

With these parameters, I want so to output (I want to keep vectors)

```
[[2 12] [3 12]]
```

This is pretty easy but I do not know if my way is very idiomatic :

```
(defn cap-poisson-samples
  "Cap poisson samples to meet the expactations
   if required"
  [data max-values]
  (mapv
    (fn [x]
      (mapv (fn [u v] (if (> u v) v u)) x max-values))
    data))
```

Someone told me that it's better to avoid nested `map` in the past but I do not know if it's true.

I know `prewalk` exists but it's not possible to pass two inputs (like my second `mapv`).
i could also use a `for` but it's heavier.

Generally speaking, I'm quite lost when I work with two vectors I have to process on same indexes. I searched in clojure;core but I did not find any.
So I generally use `for` or `mapv` depending on the fact that the index is important or not.

Thanks

Comment: the logic is just ok, i guess. There is nothing bad with inner `map` (as far as i know). I would just shorten it a bit: your comparisson function is just `min` from clojure core, so i would do this: `(mapv (partial mapv min max-values) data)`

Comment: but as soon as you know that there are just two elements in each pair, more readable (and efficient i guess) is just to compare every item, instead of mapping: `(defn cap [data [cap1 cap2]] (mapv (fn [[x1 x2]] [(min x1 cap1) (min x2 cap2)]) data))`

Comment: Thanks, the big vector has a variable size but the little ones always contains 7 integers (for every day of the week). Thanks for the answer, I did not even notice I performed a min so I just replaced the anonymous function. I prefer to keep the fn [x] form for "mathematical" readablity but I guess it has at most a minimal impact on performance (if any)

Comment: btw, if I need to map over a collection with it's indices, then I'll often use the variadic feature of `map` (e.g. `(map f coll (range (count coll)))`)